# nfs - can't see shares when outside LAN

Tags: nfs

I have a NFS server on my home LAN that I use to share out some drives to other hosts on my LAN. This works without issue.

I am away today and have added to my server's /etc/exports the external IP addresses (IPv4 and IPv6) of the LAN I am visiting. The server restarts without issue and the `showmount` command lists the exports.

I can SSH between client and server in both directions using both IPv4 and IPv6.

I have added UFW rules to the server to allow my visiting IPs the same NFS ports that I open for the LAN hosts.

I have turned off firewalls on both ends.

However on my laptop here where I am visiting I can not list the server mounts using `showmount -e`. This command works as expected on the server and on another host on the LAN. And of course I can't mount the shares.

So what have I missed?

Comment: How is the router on the server configured? Just because you can SSH doesn't mean the NFS ports are routed to WAN.

Comment: @m_krsic Ah yes. Of course. That'll be it.